# Specified column precision is greater than the maximum precision of 38

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating a new SP(Stored Procedure) in SQL Server 2008 and it will gives me an error i.e.

```
Specified column precision 52 is greater than the maximum precision of 38
```

I can't understand that why this error occurs?

Please let me explain why this error occurs and how can i solve this error.

Comment: Sorry I got my mistake and really this is a silly mistake which generated by me by mistake. I declared a parameter which datatype is decimal and by mistake i tool decimal's length 52. so it given an error because decimal maximum length id 38.

Answer (score 2):

The system told you why the error occurred.

You asked a precision of 52, but the maximum default precision is only 38. So the system can not give you the precision you asked.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx

"In SQL Server, the default maximum precision of numeric and decimal data types is 38. In earlier versions of SQL Server, the default maximum is 28."

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put a variable that has greater precision than what is stored in the table.

Check your table structure or your statement/procedure.

For other people that are looking for solutions to similar issues using hibernate, check your mapping files.

In my case, I changed precision to 38 in the hibernate mapping file (`*.hbm.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake and really this is a silly mistake which generated by me by mistake. I declared a parameter which datatype is decimal and by mistake i tool decimal's length 52. so it given an error because decimal maximum length id 38.